# mac:mysql and mysql workbench is not synchronize

Tags: mysql, macos

I have meet some problem can't solve.
I create a database in mysql workbench,and I checked in the terminal, not exist.And when I use the database in my project,I have to create the database in the terminal, if I create in the workbench and use it in my project, it will tell me that database not exists.

The test connection in workbench is successful.

```
Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| awesome            |
| myblog             |
| mydb               |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know whether your Workbench be set to automatically commit or not?  Please read [this article](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-commit-changes-in-MySql-workbench), check your auto commit settings, and let us know.

Comment: Yes,my workbench is set to automatically commit ...what should i do ?Thanks a lot.